# Sorting Date/Time Field By Date

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table which has a Date/Time field [shipStatusDate]. I need to sort by date only however, there are some null values in the Date/Time field. I am able to sort by BETWEEN dates. I provided the between dates string I am using for sorting values for the month. I have tried Cdate, DateValue() with no success, I get type mismatch and I suspect it has to do with the null values in [shipStatusDate]. Thank you for the help in advanced.

```
[status] like ""*" & statusShip & "*"" AND [shipStatusDate] BETWEEN Date()-30     AND Date()
```

Comment: edit the query to exclude where shipStatusDate is null?  This will prove whether or not it is the source of your issue.  If it is, look at using the NZ function to resolve the issue (details: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php)

Comment: NZ Function helped! Both Gustav and questioneverything help with the examples. Thank you for the link a lot of helpful information on that website!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably after something like this:

```
Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date

' and then
" ... [status] Like '*" & statusShip & "*' And (Nz([shipStatusDate], Date()) Between #" & Format(FirstDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(LastDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you want done with the null records. Either filter them out, or you could convert them to a valid date like today by:

```
[status] like ""*" & statusShip & "*"" AND nz([shipStatusDate],date()) BETWEEN Date()-30     AND Date()
```